# how to avoid exposing mutable properties in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mutable

Suppose that there a class A with property list:

```
class A {

  val list = mutableListOf<String>()
  
  fun addAText() {
    list.add("a text")
  }

}
```

but now not only method `addAText()` can add a string to the list but also everyone from everywhere.

So I solve this rewriting above code to this:

```
class A {

  private val mutList = mutableListOf<String>()

  val list: List<String>
  get() = mutList
  
  fun addAText() {
    mutList.add("a text")
  }

}
```

So question is: Is there a better way? like any syntax support or standard kotlin lib?
Additional private properties seems to be not elegant solution.

Comment: This is the best way. There's a semi-convention of giving both properties the same name, with the private one having an underscore prefix.

Comment: Private setter and public getter that creates a defensive copy? http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15

Comment: Note that (as Alex mentioned previously) although the `List` returned from the public getter is read-only, the caller could try to downcast it to `MutableList` and then modify it that way.  But this is nearly always good enough.  (If you really needed to protect against a malicious caller, you could create a truly immutable view using e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableList()`, or a defensive copy if it didn't need to reflect any future changes made through the class.)

Comment: gidds: good point. But I want to avoid mistaken usage

Answer (score 7):

That is the best approach and there is a convention using underscore. Repeat the same naming but prepend underscore for the private.

```
private val _list = mutableListOf<String>

val list: List<String>
  get() = _list
```

Is part of the naming conventio known as [backing properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names)

Is very usefull for live data

```
private val _liveText = MutableLiveData("default")
val liveText: LiveData<String>
     get()  = _liveText

fun update(text: String) {
    _liveText.value = text
}
```

So in a ViewModel you expose the observable but encapsulate the mutable.

Comment: @LunaVulpo would you rather wait for more answer os is this good enough to mark as correct? Just checking in, no rushes